# Let $\{ X^{\tau_n} \}$ be a sequence continuous stopped process. Does $E[X_t^{\tau_n}]<C$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ imply that $E[X_t]<C$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X$ be a positive continuous stochastic process. Define the sequence of stopping times
$$\tau_n := \inf \{ t:X_t>n \}, \quad n \in \mathbb N$$ and define the sequence of stopped processes $\{ X^{\tau_n} \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where  $ X^{\tau_n}:=\{X_t^{\tau_n};t \geq 0 \}.$ 
Let $C>0$ be a fixed constant. I know that 
$$E[X_t^{\tau_n}]<C \  \quad \text{for all $t$ and $n$}  \tag*{(1)}$$
and I have to show that
$$E[X_t]<C \ \quad \text{for all $t$}  \tag*{(2)}.$$
Does (1) imply (2)?
If yes, is the following enough justification?

Since X is a continuous process, $n \rightarrow \infty$ implies $\tau_n \rightarrow \infty.$ Thus, for almost all $\omega,$ 
$$X_t^{\tau_n}(\omega) = X_{t \wedge \tau_n}(\omega)=X_t(\omega) \quad \text{as $n \rightarrow \infty$}. $$
Therefore, by Fatou's lemma, for each $t$ 
$$E[X_t] \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_t^{\tau_n}]< C.$$

Comment: If $X$ is non negative, use Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Also, your condition $E(X_t^{\tau_n})<C$ a.s. makes no sense, expected values are real numbers.

Comment: @WillM.: Thank you. Yes, $X$ is non negative. Why Fatou's lemma and not DCT?

Comment: Fatou's lemma prove DCT and it is applicable with less hypothesis (but also has a less powerful conclusion).

Comment: To use the DCT you need to have a choice of dominating random variable - i.e. an integrable $Y$ such that $|X_t^{\tau_n}| \leq Y$ almost surely. The formulation given in the question doesn't lend itself to providing such a $Y$.

Comment: Thank you both.